# How to execute a clip after a buffer in a custom script tool

Tags: arcpy, clip, error-000732

I'm working on a script which

1. Buffers roads in a layer, then
2. clips the buffered roads from an area

Here is my script thus far:

```
import arcpy
import os

from arcpy import env

env.workspace = "C:/Code/Module6"

arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

Roads_to_Buffer = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
Output_Road_Buffer = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
Road_Buffer_Distance = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2)
Focus_Area = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(3)
Clipped_Buffer_Roads = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(4)

# step 1 create a buffer around the roads
arcpy.Buffer_analysis(Roads_to_Buffer, Output_Road_Buffer, Road_Buffer_Distance)

# Step 2 Clip the buffered roads from the focus area
arcpy.Clip_analysis(Output_Road_Buffer, Focus_Area, Clipped_Buffer_Roads)
```

here is a screenshot of my parameters:
[image]

However, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:\Code\Module6\Module6test.py", line 19, in <module>
    arcpy.Clip_analysis(Output_Road_Buffer, Focus_Area, Clipped_Buffer_Roads)
  File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.4\arcpy\arcpy\analysis.py",     line 56, in Clip
raise e
ExecuteError: Failed to execute. Parameters are not valid.
ERROR 000732: Input Features: Dataset C:\Code\Module6\Bufferroads does not exist or is not supported
Failed to execute (Clip).


Failed to execute (Module6Test).
```

Can anyone help me fix my script?

Comment: Your error references a dataset called Bufferroads that does not appear in either the code snippet that you posted or the parameters. I'd start looking there!

Comment: This likely isn't the cause of your error, but in your Parameters window you have `Roads Buffer Output` and `Clipped Roads` set as `Feature Dataset`.  These will *not* be [Feature Datasets](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/feature-datasets/an-overview-of-working-with-feature-datasets.htm), but should probably be set as [Feature Class](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/feature-classes/a-quick-tour-of-feature-classes.htm)

Comment: kindly save ur script as .py manually

Answer (score 1):

Your output needs to be either a shapefile or a geodatabase feature class.  Currently you aren't outputting either:

```
C:\Code\Module6\Bufferroads does not exist
```

If this were a shapefile the output would be `C:\Code\Module6\Bufferroads.shp`, and if it were a geodatabase feature class the output would be something like `C:\Code\Module6\output.gdb\Bufferroads`

You need to make the value you input for `Output_Road_Buffer = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)` to be either a shapefile or a feature class.

In your Parameters window you can select either of those.  Selecting Shapefile will limit that output to Shapefiles only.  Selecting Feature Class will allow you to output either Shapefile or gdb Feature Class.  Using the Dialog that appears when entering that value, if you save within a Geodatabase it will automatically make it a gdb Feature Class, and if you save within a folder it will automatically make it a Shapefile.

[image]